# error: cannot find symbol [compiler error]

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Hey I'm just starting my first programming class with java. In class, we made a very basic code for adding up numbers in a harmonic series. I get an error: cannot find symbol for x on the line total+= (1.0/(x+1)).

Here's the code:

```
public class Group1
{
public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        foo(3);
    }
public static void foo(int n)
    {
    double total = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++);
        {
        total+= (1.0/(x+1));
        }
    System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any answers. I've been messing around trying get it  an hour. I can't believe I couldn't find something so simple. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have a dangling `;` after the `for` statement. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: This is why K&R indent style is superior. (Flamewar: now! :) )

Comment: @Amadan What does that have to do with the dangling semicolon?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: If you write the opening brace on the same line immediately after the `for` parentheses, it is obvious when you have inserted an extra colon. In Whitesmiths and all other styles that put the opening brace in the next line, it is easy to overlook `for(...);` as just another function call - semicolons at the end of the line are not unusual. But it would be very unusual to write `for (...); {` on a line.

Comment: @Amadan Ah, agreed. I too favor the the `{` on the same line. I was confused because you said *indent* style (when it's really a curly-brace-line style issue). My bad.

Comment: @Amadan Or just an IDE with bracket highlighting with any style.

Comment: @chrylis That wouldn't have given the advantage that Amadan pointed out - the `{` takes the place of this mistaken `;` at the end of the line.  The given code is valid, other than the scope of `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove semi colon at the end of for statement. Basically in your code scope of variable is inside for loop only and since you are closing the for loop by putting a semi colon, x is gone after that.

Comment: Thank you for explaining out the details of what I did wrong. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `;` at the end of the for loop. By adding semi colon at the end, you are limiting the scope of the variable x

```
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++); // <--- remove this semi colon
```

Answer (score -1):

change `for (int x = 0; x < n; x++);` to `for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)`

Comment: This adds nothing to the discussion, and is more verbose than the existing answer.